# Remove list items from within list of list

Tags: python, list

How do I remove all `'d'` and `'e'`

```
abc = [('a','b','c','d','e'), ('a','b','c','d','e'), 
 ('a','b','c','d','e'), ('a','b','c','d','e')]

abc.remove('d')
```

`ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

```
abc.remove('d', 'e')
```

`TypeError: remove() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`

```
finalList = []
for l in abc:
    finalList.append([i[3] for i in l])
```

`IndexError: string index out of range`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension to check if any of the sub elements are in your "blacklist" and keep the rest.

```
>>> [tuple(i for i in sub if i not in {'d', 'e'}) for sub in abc]
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove an element from a tuple. However, the following procedure can solve your problem.

```
abc = [('a','b','c','d','e'), ('a','b','c','d','e'), ('a','b','c','d','e'), ('a','b','c','d','e')]
l = [] // Creating an empty list

// Appending all tuples of abc in l as LISTS
for item in abc:
    l.append(list(item))
// Removing the unnecessary elements

for item in l:
    item.remove('d')
    item.remove('e')
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [('a','b','c','d','e'), ('a','b','c','d','e'), 
 ('a','b','c','d','e'), ('a','b','c','d','e')]

print ([tuple(s for s in x if s not in ['d','e']) for x in l])
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```